# How to get around iframes with WordPress?

Tags: iframe

I'm working in WordPres 4.9.5.  I have some projects that involve data from a third party application called Wrike.  The easiest way for me to display the data is through an iframe.  I'm placing the following iframe onto one of my pages...

```
<iframe src="https://www.wrike.com/ui/get_workspace_snapshot?snapshotId=longvalue|shortvalue" width="6500" height="675" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I prefer not to deal with iframes at all.  If there is alternative way I can call that data into a WordPress page, can someone provide any pointers?

Comment: That would be more of a question for the makers of Wrike, not WordPress, since it depends on whether or not Wrike has APIs or some other way to access their data. A quick glance at their site reveals they do have an API - https://developers.wrike.com/ - you would create code that pulls the data from their API, then outputs whatever HTML you want it to, and you could then either place your code in a plugin (if you want this functionality even if you change themes) or within your custom theme (if you include a lot of styling/formatting in your code and it's tied to the theme).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be more of a question for the makers of Wrike, not WordPress, since it depends on whether or not Wrike has APIs or some other way to access their data. A quick glance at their site reveals they do have an API - developers.wrike.com - you would create code that pulls the data from their API, then outputs whatever HTML you want it to, and you could then either place your code in a plugin (if you want this functionality even if you change themes) or within your custom theme (if you include a lot of styling/formatting in your code and it's tied to the theme).